# Why doesn't my if-then statement in Scratch ever trigger?

Tags: if-statement, mit-scratch

I have been using Scratch for a few months, but am suddenly completely and inexplicably stuck. 
I can't get a simple if-then condition to trigger.
After stripping down to the bare essentials, I have this:
[image]

the variable d successfully changes when I press space, but never triggers the if-then, even when d=5, as confirmed by the display.
What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that it gets into the when clause? In my idea, the only possible reason can be that, it does not get into the when clause.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the variable to the expression, like this (Notice the orange color of `d`, drag it from the section "Variables"):

[image]